# expressing a natural number as a sum of three natural numbers and finding the sum of their product

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I have three natural numbers $a, b, c$ such that $a + b + c = n$ and I'm looking for $\sum abc$.

So far I've figured out that the generating function for $p(n,3)$ might be $\frac{x^3}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$ but I'm not sure if I'm correct because none of $a,b,c$ can be zero and I don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: What are you summing over? All possible vaules of $a$, $b$ and $c$? How does the generating function for $p(n,3)$ get into it?

Comment: It's a summation over all natural numbers such that $a+b+c=n$. I thought that I would use a generating function for a partition of number n into 3 parts to get all the possible combinations, but I'm stuck.

Comment: You can't do it that way, both because $p(n,3)$ is for unordered partitions and not for ordered partitions, and because it doesn't track the product you're summing over, which is different for different partitions counted by $p(n,3)$.

Comment: Ok I understand now, obviously it needs to be a ordered partition. So what is the way it could be solved?

Comment: Do you want this for general $n$? Where did you get the problem? Do you have reason to believe it can be solved?

Comment: This is the original task from my homework sheet, I'm sure it's got a solution:

Let  $T{n} = {(a, b, c) ∈ N^3; a + b + c = n}$ . Determine ∑abc

Answer (score 0):

A partition of $n$ items into groups of $a$, $b$ and $c$ items corresponds to selecting $2$ of $n+2$ objects to be partitions walls. Then $abc$ counts the number of ways of selecting one item from each group. Equivalently, we can select $5$ of $n+2$ objects and regard the $2^{nd}$ and $4^{th}$ as partition walls and the $1^{st}$, $3^{rd}$ and $5^{th}$ as selected items. Thus the desired sum is $\binom{n+2}5$.